# Harp Multiple Glissando

Tags: notation, harp, glissando

I don't know if it is the correct term, but how to write in the score a harp glissando where the hands pass many times from the start note to the endnote?

Here's an audio example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k__35AsIYI9JmHycT1vBEBNfbLu_MbG0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found what might be the answer: [Slow Cluster Glissando](http://sites.siba.fi/web/harpnotation/manual/sliding-sounds/glissando/slow-cluster-glissando)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The classical solution I can find is to notate multiple glissando lines, emphasized by an explicit note "up and down ad libitum".
[image]

(Source: Symphony No. 9, Ralph Vaughan Williams)